# Mystery game from 2000s set on an island with a bell

Tags: story-identification, video-games

I played the game on PC, but probably not on release. It was definitely before 2010.

The game started with the main character "dying" in a car crash. The character wakes up on an island with people that supposedly died in other events (I vaguely remember one of the NPCs died in 9-11).

The character can explore the map, but when a bell rings, he faints and gets put back in the camp.

Comment: What was the gameplay like? Was it full 3-D? 2-D? Isometric? Visual novel? "First person" free-roaming? Myst-style slideshow? Point-and-click adventure? RPG?

Comment: We also recommend you visit https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11995/how-to-ask-a-good-video-game-story-id-question and https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question for prompts to get more details to [edit] into your question. Also, please visit the [tour]. :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is  [*Next Life*](https://www.metacritic.com/game/pc/next-life).

> **Adam Raichl is instantly killed in a horrific accident one evening when his SUV suddenly collides with an oncoming truck.** But, did he in fact die? Astonished to awaken in the presence of others, Adam quickly realizes that they are all stranded on a large and desolate island. **Why does everyone talk about historical events as if they just happened yesterday?** Why are mysterious messages hidden all over the island waiting to be discovered? **Why does everyone fall asleep when the bell tower rings three times?** What Adam first thought was a dream turns into a dark, disturbing reality and a thrilling mystery that Adam must untangle if he ever wants to unlock the secrets of Next Life.

Comment: Yes! This is it! I tried to Googling for it, but my descriptions kept on leading me to :( ...... probably because of the island description.